# Convert a string rule into a dataframe in python using regex or pattern matching

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can we convert the following string rule into a structured data frame ?

My input is a string (which is essentially a rule), following is an example of the input string :

WHEN Male Height (Inches) <= 2.30 && Female Height (Inches) > 1 && Male Weight (Kgs) <= 350 &&  Male Weight (Kgs)  <= 349 THEN Final Output =[[75]]

The resultant data frame should look like :

```
Variable                      Sign       Value
Male Height (inches)          <=          2.30
Female Height (inches)         >           1
Male Weight (kgs)             <=          350
Male Weight (kgs)             <=          349
Final Output                   =          75
```

where variable corresponds to X1..Xn in the rule , signs and their values are implicit. And final value in data frame is Y which is the variable after "THEN" in the rule.

Comment: Please share a sample dataframe with expected output. Also, share your attempt.

Comment: Hi @Mayank, someone suggested me to use regex on this , so was exploring regex but don't have the try as of now , also the sample data frame is the resultant dataframe mentioned in the question

Comment: In my understanding, what you mentioned in question, is your expected output. Can you please paste sample input.

Comment: @MayankPorwal I have updated the question and added the clarification. My input is basically a string and output is a dataframe .

Answer (score 0):

Do `explode` then do multiple `split`, `s` is your string:

```
df=pd.Series(s).str.split(' THEN ').explode().str.strip('WHEN ').str.split(' && ').explode().str.split(' ',expand=True)
    0   1       2
0  X1  <=    2.30
0  X2   >       1
0  X3  <=     350
0  X3  <=     349
0  X2   >       1
0   Y   =  [[75]]
```

Comment: What if my X1 and X2 variables are also strings with spaces in it as when I ran this on my actual string , it broke with spaces . For ex my actual string looks like :
WHEN male height (inches) <= 2.30 && female height (inches) > 1 && male weight (kgs) <= 350 &&  male weight (kgs)  <= 349 && female weight ( lbs) >1 THEN final outpur =[[75]]

Answer (score 0):

You can do a `regex` with `pandas`:

```
pattern = pattern = '(?P<Variable>[^A-Z\<\>\=\&]+)\s?(?P<Sign>[\<\>\=]+)\W*(?P<Value>[\d\.]+)'
pd.Series(s).str.extractall(pattern)
```

Output:

```
                         Variable Sign Value
  match                                     
0 0         male height (inches)    <=  2.30
  1       female height (inches)     >     1
  2            male weight (kgs)    <=   350
  3            male weight (kgs)    <=   349
  4                 final output     =    75
```

Comment: Hi @Quang , I have updated the question since I had many spaces with in the variable names and the code was breaking

Comment: See updated, this works for lowercase variable names.

Comment: Thanks @Quang for the help, much appreciated . And one last question ? what change should I make if I have Proper casing of letters like "Male Height (Inches)"

Comment: updated the question with proper casing. Apologies for keep coming again